# How to determine the DBMS from Connection object

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource, rdbms

I have a usecase of supporting multiple RDBMS. User should define the data source as a prerequisite and at the code level i have to determine which RDBMS the user going to connect with and provide specific RDBMS attributes.

Eg:,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver           jdbc:mysql://hostname/ databaseName
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port Number:databaseName
```

As shown above we can retrieve connection url or may be driver name and identify the RDBMS. But i want to clarify what is the best way to identify which RDBMS user is using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found out by following this also you can identify. DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = con.getMetaData();
String dbName=databaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName();

Answer (score 3):

This is really simple. See [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
String databaseName = databaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName();
String userName = databaseMetaData.getUserName();
```

**UPDATE** To answer ***@dnWick*** comment.

Yes, This `DatabaseMetaData` support for the wide range of `RDBMS`. Through the `DatabaseMetaData` interface we can obtain metadata about the database that we have connected.  For instance, we can see what tables are defined in the database, and what columns each table has, Even we can check supported features for the database we have connected.

**Example** We can see if a database has support for multiple transactions, supports for UNION or not, etc.,

Comment: Thanks i put the same solution as a comment.. I want to know will it be applicable to any RDBMS . I presume yes. If you have any thoughts on this please share..